# why should one prefer call_user_func_array over regular calling of function?

Tags: php, function, callback

```
function foobar($arg, $arg2) {
    echo __FUNCTION__, " got $arg and $arg2\n";
}
foobar('one','two'); // OUTPUTS : foobar got one and two 

call_user_func_array("foobar", array("one", "two")); // // OUTPUTS : foobar got one and two
```

As I can see both regular one and  `call_user_func_array` method both outputs same, then why should one prefer it?

In which scenario regular calling method will fail but `call_user_func_array` will not?

Can I get any such example?

Thank you

Comment: `call_user_func_array` is mostly used in dynamic contexts, when you don't know which function you will call and what arguments you are going to pass beforehand.

Comment: cant we user regular method for array of arguments ? @ elclanrs

Answer (score 117, accepted):

1. You have an array with the arguments for your function which is of indeterminate length.

   ```
   $args = someFuncWhichReturnsTheArgs();

   foobar( /* put these $args here, you do not know how many there are */ );
   ```

   The alternative would be:

   ```
   switch (count($args)) {
       case 1:
           foobar($args[0]);
           break;
       case 2:
           foobar($args[0], $args[1]);
           break;
       ...
   }
   ```

   Which is not a solution.

The use case for this may be rare, but when you come across it you *need* it.

Comment: This particular problem is now solved in PHP 5.6 using argument unpacking: `foobar(...$args);`

Comment: What will be the argument list in the definition of `foobar` function ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Assume it’s using `func_get_args()` for the sake of discussion.

Comment: This is not the common way to declare a function. The answer does not mention it as well and makes the thing obscure.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed It doesn’t matter how the function is implemented. You may also assume all its parameters are optional and/or the function (name) itself is a variable. This is purely about variable argument *calls*.

Comment: @deceze, where in your answer do you make use of `call_user_func_array` ?

Comment: @Istiaque I'm assuming you know what `call_user_func_array` does, I'm answering the question of what situation you'd use it in and what the alternative would look like.

Comment: @deceze, why to use `call_user_func_array` needs the knowledge as to what role it plays. Trying to understand the whole unclear scenario.

Answer (score 14):

> In which scenario regular calling method will fail but call_user_func_array will not ?

If you don't know beforehand how many arguments you're going to pass to your function, it would be advisable to use `call_user_func_array()`; the only alternative is a `switch` statement or a bunch of conditions to accomplish a predefined subset of possibilities.

Another scenario is where the function to be called is not known beforehand, e.g. `array($obj, 'method')`; this is also where you could use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func).

```
$fn = array($obj, 'method');
$args = [1, 2, 3];
call_user_func_array($fn, $args);
```

Note that using `call_user_func_*` functions can't be used to call private or protected methods.

The alternative to all of this is to make your functions accept an array as its only argument:

```
myfn([1, 2, 3]);
```

However, this eliminates the possibility to type-hint each argument in your function declaration and is generally considered a code smell.

Comment: `If you don't know beforehand how many arguments you're going to pass to your function, it would be advisable to use call_user_func_array();` - can you elaborate with relevant code sample ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed the example is given once paragraph down, were you expecting something else?

Comment: Give us the definition of `$obj` and its `method` as well.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed `$obj` has a function called `method` that takes three arguments ...

Comment: so you know that you have to pass 3 args. So what role does `call_user_func_array` play here ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed actually, my answer starts by asserting that you _don't know_ the number of arguments (and in some cases even the method name); so actually giving any definition wouldn't serve the purpose of the answer.

Comment: can you provide a real time example where function name and number of arguments are not known beforehand ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed one example could be delegation pattern whereby you proxy arguments to a variable callback.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed if you need an example, you will probably not have a use for it :)

Answer (score 8):

You should prefer calling the function as you'd do regularly. Use `call_user_func_array` with dynamic arguments. For example:

```
function func(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  return "$arg1, $arg2, $arg3";
}

func(1, 2, 3); //=> "1, 2, 3"

$args = range(5,7); // dynamic arguments
call_user_func_array('func', $args); //=> "5, 6, 7"
```

Comment: What happens if the arrays length does not match the number of parameters in the function and the function does not use default values? An error? Or do the other arguments just get null (if to few) or ignored (if to many)?

Comment: can you clarify more as to what you mean by `dynamic arguments` ?

Answer (score 7):

`call_user_func_array` performs "uncurrying", which is the opposite of "currying".

The following applies to all of PHP's "callables" (named functions, closures, methods, `__invoke`, etc.), so for simplicity let's ignore the differences and just focus on closures.

If we want to accept multiple arguments, PHP lets us do that with 3 different APIs. The usual way is this:

```
$usual = function($a, $b, $c, $d) {
             return $a + $b + $c + $d;
         };
$result = $usual(10, 20, 30, 40);  // $result == 100
```

Another way is called [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) form:

```
$curried = function($a) {
               return function($b) use ($a) {
                          return function($c) use ($a, $b) {
                                     return function($d) use ($a, $b, $c) {
                                                return $a + $b + $c + $d;
                                            };
                                 };
                      };
           };
$result = call_user_func(
              call_user_func(
                  call_user_func(
                      $curried(10),
                      20),
                  30),
              40);  // $result == 100
```

The advantage is that all curried functions can be called in the same way: give them one argument.

If more arguments are required, more curried functions are returned, which 'remember' the previous arguments. This allows us to pass in some arguments now and the rest later.

There are some problems with this:

- Clearly it's very tedious to write and call functions in this way.
- If we provide curried functions, they'll be awkward whenever their 'memory' ability isn't needed.
- If we rely on the 'memory' ability of curried functions, we'll be disappointed when other people's code doesn't provide it.

We can fix all of these issues by using a [conversion function](http://chriswarbo.net/blog/2014-02-21-partial_application___currying_in_php.html) (disclaimer: that's my blog). This lets us write and call our functions in the usual way, but gives them the same 'memory' ability as if they were curried:

```
$curried = curry(function($a, $b, $c, $d) {
                     return $a + $b + $c + $d;
                 });
$result1 = $curried(10, 20, 30, 40);  // $result1 = 100
$result2 = call_user_func($curried(10, 20), 30, 40); // $result2 = 100
```

The third way is called *uncurried* and takes all of its arguments in one:

```
$uncurried = function($args) {
                 return $args[0] + $args[1] + $args[2] + $args[3];
             };
$result = $uncurried([10, 20, 30, 40]);  // $result == 100
```

Just like with curried functions, uncurried functions can all be called with one argument, although this time it's an array. We still face the same compatibility problems as curried functions: if we choose to use uncurried functions, we can't rely on everyone else choosing the same. Hence we also need a conversion function for uncurrying. That's what `call_user_func_array` does:

```
$uncurried = function($args) use ($usual) {
                 return call_user_func_array($usual, $args);
             };
$result1 = $usual(10, 20, 30, 40);  // $result1 = 100
$result2 = $uncurried([10, 20, 30, 40]); // $result2 = 100
```

Interestingly, we can get rid of that extra `function($args)` wrapper (a process known as "eta-reduction") by currying `call_user_func_array`:

```
$uncurried = curry('call_user_func_array', $usual);

$result = $uncurried([10, 20, 30, 40]); // $result == 100
```

Unfortunately `call_user_func_array` isn't as smart as `curry`; it won't automatically convert between the two. We can write our own `uncurry` function which has that ability:

```
function uncurry($f)
{
    return function($args) use ($f) {
               return call_user_func_array(
                          $f,
                          (count(func_get_args()) > 1)? func_get_args()
                                                      : $args);
           };
}

$uncurried = uncurry($usual);
$result1 = $uncurried(10, 20, 30, 40); // $result1 == 100
$result2 = $uncurried([10, 20, 30, 40]); // $result2 == 100
```

These conversion functions show that PHP's "usual" way of defining functions is actually redundant: if we replaced PHP's "usual" functions with 'smart' curried or uncurried ones, lots of code would carry on working. If we did that, it's better to curry everything and selectively uncurry as needed, since that's easier than going the other way around.

Unfortunately, some things which expect a variable number of arguments using `func_get_args` would break, as well as functions with default argument values.

Interestingly, default values are just a special form of currying. We could mostly do without them if we put those arguments *first* instead of last, and provided a bunch of alternative definitions which curry in the defaults. For example:

```
$defaults = function($a, $b, $c = 30, $d = 40) {
                return $a + $b + $c + $d;
            };
$def1 = $defaults(10, 20, 30, 40);  // $def1 == 100
$def2 = $defaults(10, 20, 30);      // $def2 == 100
$def3 = $defaults(10, 20);          // $def3 == 100

$curried = function($d, $c, $a, $b) {
               return $a + $b + $c + $d;
           };
$curriedD  = $curried(40);
$curriedDC = $curriedD(30);

$cur1 = $curried(10, 20, 30, 40);  // $cur1 == 100
$cur2 = $curriedD(10, 20, 30);     // $cur2 == 100
$cur3 = $curriedDC(10, 20);        // $cur3 == 100
```

Answer (score 5):

As of php 5.6, to pass an *array* instead of an *argument list* to a function simply precede the array with an ellipsis (this is called "argument unpacking").

```
function foo($var1, $var2, $var3) {
   echo $var1 + $var2 + var3;
}

$array = [1,2,3];

foo(...$array);  // 6
// same as call_user_func_array('foo',$array);
```

The difference between `call_user_func_array()` and *variable functions* as of php 5.6 is that variable functions do not allow you to call a static method:

```
$params = [1,2,3,4,5];

function test_function() {
  echo implode('+',func_get_args()) .'='. array_sum(func_get_args())."\r\n";
}    

// Normal function as callback
$callback_function = 'test_function';
call_user_func_array($callback_function,$params); // 1+2+3+4+5=15
$callback_function(...$params); // 1+2+3+4+5=15

class TestClass
{
  static function testStaticMethod() {
    echo implode('+',func_get_args()) .'='. array_sum(func_get_args())."\r\n";
  }

  public function testMethod() {
    echo implode('+',func_get_args()) .'='. array_sum(func_get_args())."\r\n";
  }
}

// Class method as callback
$obj = new TestClass;
$callback_function = [$obj,'testMethod'];
call_user_func_array($callback_function,$params); // 1+2+3+4+5=15
$callback_function(...$params); // 1+2+3+4+5=15

// Static method callback
$callback_function = 'TestClass::testStaticMethod';
call_user_func_array($callback_function,$params); // 1+2+3+4+5=15
$callback_function(...$params); // Fatal error: undefined function
```

Php 7 adds the ability to call static methods via a variable function, so as of php 7 *this* difference no longer exists.  In conclusion, `call_user_func_array()` gives your code greater compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Demo {

    public function function1() {
        echo 'in function 1';
    }
}

$obj = new Demo();

$function_list = get_class_methods('Demo');

print_r($function_list);  //Array ( [0] => function1 )

call_user_func_array(array($obj, $function_list[0]), array()); 

// Output => in function 1

?>
```