# Array of variables to function parameter

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters

I've an array like this:

```
$params = ["Hello" => "Hello World", "Text" => "This is a text"];
```

And I want to call function:

```
myFunction("Hello World", "This is a text");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `myFunction($params["Hello"], $params["Text"]);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526060/why-should-one-prefer-call-user-func-array-over-regular-calling-of-function

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`call_user_func_array()`](https://secure.php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
call_user_func_array('myFunction', $params);
```

Or if you have PHP 5.6+, you can use the [`...`](https://secure.php.net/functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list) operator:

```
myFunction(...$params);
```

<sub>NOTE: This only works with *numeric* arrays, not *associative* arrays</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
$params = ["Hello" => "Hello World", "Text" => "This is a text"];
```

Using `call_user_func_array`

```
call_user_func_array('myFunction', array_values($params));
```

Also you can do this:

```
myFunction($params['Hello'], $params['Text']);

function myFunction($h, $t){
    echo $h." - ".$t;
}
```

Comment: You're killing it http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers

Comment: @AbraCadaver, What does it means??

Comment: You are doing a great job, Top PHP Answerer last 30 Days.