# Argument of call_user_func_array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I Need to use `call_user_func_array`, but my array is too big, from the documentation i only got to use array values in the argument list. Is there no way to use the same array as argument of the callback function.

```
mixed call_user_func_array ( callable $callback , array $param_arr )
```

**My Code:**

```
echo call_user_func_array("myFirstFunction" , array("1" , "2" , "3")); 

function myFirstFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){
    return $arg1 . $arg2 . $arg3;
}
```

My Question is if i have array with 50  or more values than how can use this function?

Comment: Why do you have to use `call_user_func_array`?

Comment: pass an array to an function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [func_get_args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526060/why-should-one-prefer-call-user-func-array-over-regular-calling-of-function)

```
echo call_user_func_array("myFirstFunction" , array("1" , "2" , "3")); 

function myFirstFunction(){
    $arguments = func_get_args(); //Now, $arguments is an array, you can process further
    return implode("", $arguments);
}
```

Result:

```
123
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/579166)

Comment: for php7 see http://docs.php.net//functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list . But if you really want/have to pass 50+ values to a function isn't an array/iterator as parameter better anyway?

Comment: Hello sir, would you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Given the information provided, no, not really. Something like http://codepad.org/ZvsLuB91 , but it depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: So from your suggestion if i have some big size array than go with `foreach...` not `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: I those are the alternatives without further information, then: yes (tentative)

Comment: Thanks for the help both if you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
<?php

echo array_reduce(['1', '2', '3'], "myFirstFunction");

function myFirstFunction($prev, $arg){
    return $prev . $arg;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some explanation for this?? I really don't know that how this solve my problem.

Comment: array_reduce will reduce the array to one single value using the callback function, myFirstFunction.

Comment: That is under the assumption that reducing the array fits the OP's needs. From the rather generic question (which triggers at least in me the generic answer "just don't" ;-) ) we don't know what's actually required.

Comment: What are `$prev, $arg` things do here??

Comment: Thanks for the help.